# PySide / PyQt: How to auto-tab into the next entry field

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qlineedit

How do you make a lineEdit widget automatically tab into the next lineEdit widget after you're done filling it?

I've set a lineEdit widget to have a max length with `self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(4))` so you can enter a maximum of 4 characters. Once this limit is reached, how do you put the focus into the widget that's next in line?

I'm assuming you use one of the following: `setFocusPolicy()`, `setFocusProxy()`, `setFocus()`, or `focusNextPrevChild()`. I think `focusNextPrevChild()` is most promising but that's a method for QGraphicsWidget.

Full code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def myChanges(self):
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(4)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(557, 351)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 557, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit, self.lineEdit_2)

        self.myChanges()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think `QWidget::nextInFocusChain` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me. Not sure if it is the optimal way of coding though.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def myChanges(self):
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(4)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(557, 351)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 130, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        #I did it like this for tab
        self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(self.tabNext)

    def self.tabNext(self):
        if len(self.LineEdit.text()) == 4:
            self.lineEdit_2.setFocus()
```